# Haskell cast higher kinded types

Tags: haskell, types, casting, type-kinds

This code is compiling:

```
trigger :: (Typeable n) => n () -> IO ()
trigger n = case (cast n) of
  Just n' -> n'
  Nothing -> error "n is not IO"
```

But if I add parenthesis it doesn't anymore:

```
-- not compiling
trigger' :: (forall n. (Typeable n) => n ()) -> IO ()
trigger' n = case (cast n) of
  Just n' -> n'
  Nothing -> error "n is not IO"
```

It says "No instance for (Typeable n) arising from a use of ‘cast’".
Why?

In practice I need the second form because in my program I use data types that have `forall`:

```
data Foo = Foo {a :: (Typeable n) => n ()}

trigger' :: Foo -> IO ()
trigger' (Foo n) = case (cast n) of
  Just n' -> n'
  Nothing -> error "n is not IO"
```

Comment: It could be that you're saying that `n` is `Typeable` and not `n ()`.  What happens if you do `Typeable (n ()) => n () -> IO ()`?

Comment: @bheklilr: `trigger :: Typeable (n ()) => n () -> IO ()` is compiling but not `trigger' :: (Typeable (n ()) ⇒  n ()) →  IO ()`

Comment: Note that `f :: Foo -> Void; f (Foo a) = unConst (a :: Const Void ())` should type check, making `Foo` uninhabited. You might want to have an existential instead of universal.

Comment: An implementation which of compiles is dead simple: `trigger' n = n`. `cast` gives you a type error because there is no way to determine the type of the input - the polymorphic type must be instantiated before application and in doing so a *specific* `n` must be chosen, but there is no type information from which to infer this `n`.

Answer (score 2):

```
trigger :: (Typeable n) => n () -> IO ()
```

"For any `n` that is `Typeable`, I can turn a `n ()` into an `IO ()`

```
trigger' :: (forall n. (Typeable n) => n ()) -> IO ()
```

"I can turn a value which can typed `n ()` for *every* `n` that is `Typeable` into an `IO ()`"

The second doesn't really make sense; there *are* no values of the required type to give it (other than `undefined`). Even if there were, there would be no need to use `cast`; since the argument can be assigned *every* `n ()` type you can just return it as is; it's already an `IO ()` as a special case of being every `n ()`, so you shouldn't even need `trigger` (except perhaps to pin down an ambiguous type). This is almost certainly not what you want.

The first signature is what you would need if you had an existential type; if you can build `Foo`s containing any `n ()` (provided it's `Typeable`), and you later want to be able to run them *if* they happen to contain an `IO ()`. I suspect that this is actually what you want, and you have accidentally defined your data type incorrectly, rather than the problem being in `trigger`.

Consider this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}

module Foo where

import Data.Typeable (Typeable, cast)

data Foo = Foo { a :: Typeable n => n () }

data Bar = Bar { bar :: forall n. Typeable n => n () }
data Baz = forall n. Typeable n => Baz { baz :: n () }


trigger :: Typeable n => n () -> IO ()
trigger n = case (cast n) of
    Just n' -> n'
    Nothing -> error "n is not IO"
```

Your `Foo` is equivalent to `Bar`, not to `Baz`:

```
λ :t Foo
Foo :: (forall (n :: * -> *). Typeable n => n ()) -> Foo
*Foo
λ :t Bar
Bar :: (forall (n :: * -> *). Typeable n => n ()) -> Bar
*Foo
λ :t Baz
Baz :: Typeable n => n () -> Baz
```

The implicit `forall` is placed at the beginning of the type signature of the *field* `a`, rather than quantifying over the whole constructor. Consequently you've asked that the field `a` *is* `forall n. Typeable n => n ()`, instead of the constructor working on any `n ()` and the field containing some particular but unknown `n ()`.

And we can see that `Baz` works with `trigger` the way you seem to want it to:

```
*Foo
λ case Baz (putStrLn "yay") of Baz x -> trigger x
yay
it :: ()
```

While for `Foo`, if you can get its field out you can use it directly as an `IO ()` without needing any cast, but there's no way to actually put something into a `Foo` in the first place:

```
λ case Foo undefined of Foo x -> putStrLn "weird" >> x
weird
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Because "weird" is actually printed you can see that the type-checker accepted this expression; it was perfectly fine with the idea that the hypothetical contents of a `Foo` would be usable as an `IO ()`, with no need for `trigger` at all. But I've handwaved-away the problem actually constructing a `Foo` in the first place; it's basically impossible without using something like `undefined`. This is what makes me think it's your data declaration that is incorrect, rather than `trigger`.

But if there's something about your real use-case that makes the data type wrapping a polymorphic field more reasonable (if there were more constraints than `Typeable` it could be *possible* to use), and it also doesn't work to simply dispense with `trigger` and make use of the contained polymorphism to "cast" to a more specific type, then we'll need more information to address your actual use case.